# Software Instruments

Tags: java, android, audio

I really enjoyed the music apps on the iPhone, like Ocarnia by Smule and I have always wanted to create a music app for Android. Is there some sort of API/Framework that you can use to create software instruments/create "styled" sounds? 
Thanks!

****EDIT****
I found a Java Music programming API called "JFugue", but it cannot be built in Android, due to its lack of Java MIDI support... Is there something like "JFugue" available?

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about those apps.

but there are a few different ways you could achieve musical type applications on android.

[MediaPlayback](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) <--- will give you an overview of how to use MediaPlayer object to load and play your own sound files.

[MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) <---more in-depth look at how the MediaPlayer object works.

[SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) <--- an alternative to MediaPlayer. SoundPool was designed to hold multiple sounds and is capable of playing them accross multiple streams. MediaPlayer on the other hand can only have one piece of media loaded at a time.

and ToneGenerator but I have to go now. You'll have to search around for that one yourself, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches you might take

You can include instrument samples as application resources, and play them with [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)/[SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html). For more information, see the [media player topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

You also can take a more procedural approach, where you dynamically generate the actual audio samples yourself, and then play them back using [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html).

Android does have limited midi support via the [JetPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/jetplayer.html) class. But it doesn't support dynamic generation of midi events, it can only play a pre-existing midi file.

Comment: Remember Android is Linux, and on Linux a “file” can be a pipe. Does JetPlayer work if you tell it to read from a named pipe, to which another thread is writing?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the midi file format, but I doubt it would be very friendly for dynamic generation of midi events, especially if you need more than a single track. You would have to write out/generate all of the first track before you could start generating the second track. And each track encodes its size in the header, but for a dynamic generation scenario, there really isn't any pre-set size, you just want to keep on generating data. You might be able to hack something together using this approach, but it won't be easy or pretty :)

Answer (score 1):

There are APIs on Android that can be used to make software instruments, and the other answers covered some of them.

But there's a much bigger problem, which is the ridiculously high latency (that is, the delay from the time you issue the software command to the time that the sound comes out the speaker). On most Android hardware, it's something like 400 ms, which is unacceptable for even a "toy" musical instrument (that's almost a quarter note at a moderate tempo!)

Search for "android audio latency" and you'll see thousands of comments from pissed-off developers, but no real solutions. Google is certainly aware of the problem, but nobody knows when they'll fix it. Until they do, Android is basically useless for music-making software.